# returning query result to a list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am working on a project where I am phasing out Entity framework from an existing system.

I got

```
public List<GSP> GetOwnAirline()
        { 
            var res = from own in entity.GSP where own.Description == "Own Airline" select own;
            return res.ToList();
        }
```

To bypass this i did

```
   public List<GSP> GetOwnAirline()
        {

            string get_ = "SELECT * FROM " + Adm.schema_ + "Adm.GSP WHERE Description = 'Own Airline'";
            ccs = new SqlConnection(Adm.COnnectionString);
            //convey transaction to db
            cmd = ccs.CreateCommand();
            ccs.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = get_;
            var res =cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            ccs.Close();

            return res.ToList();
        }
```

But the.ToList seems not to be recognised in this situation.
Where did i go wrong guys ?

Comment: first show your content ( Result Data )

Comment: Is there a reason why you're converting from EF to old school ADO.Net?

Comment: Yes, The system is showing performance issues. My seniors asked to make a version of it without EF (its a trial).

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn where you use this `GetOwnAirline` method? is it ok to return DataTable or DataSet from this method?

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteScalar returns a scalar - like an integer value. It can't be converted to a list.

If you're using Ado.Net you have to either return a DataTable or a DataReader to get the result. There is no way to return a List directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code.

1. ExecuteScalar returns a single value as pointed out by TGH.
2. Basically, you use ToList when you have some sort of Array or IEnumerable. As, in your case, it is a single int value, so, it can't be applied here.
3. You can use ExecuteReader here to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public List<GSP> GetOwnAirline()
    {
        List<GSP> lstGSP = new List<GSP>();
        using (ccs = new SqlConnection(Adm.COnnectionString))
        {
            string get_ = "SELECT * FROM " + Adm.schema_ + "Adm.GSP WHERE Description = 'Own Airline'";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(get_, ccs))
            {

                ccs.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    GSP objGSP = new GSP();
                    Fill(objGSP, rdr);//method
                    lstGSP.Add(objGSP);
                }
                ccs.Close();
            }
        }

        return lstGSP;
    }



public static void Fill(object LogicObject, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader SqlDataReader)
        {
            Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> props = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in LogicObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                props.Add(p.Name, p);
            //foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Row.Table.Columns)

            for (int i = 0; i < SqlDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                string name = SqlDataReader.GetName(i);
                if (SqlDataReader[name] != DBNull.Value && props.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    object item = SqlDataReader[name];
                    PropertyInfo p = props[name];
                    if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                    {
                        if (p.PropertyType != SqlDataReader.GetFieldType(i))
                            item = Convert.ChangeType(item, p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (p.PropertyType != SqlDataReader.GetFieldType(i))
                            item = Convert.ChangeType(item, p.PropertyType);
                    }

                    p.SetValue(LogicObject, item, null);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exucute scalar will return you scalar. Therefore you will have to create the object of type GSP and add to list.
an alternate way of doing this can be

```
public List<GSP> GetOwnAirline()
    {

        string get_ = "SELECT * FROM " + Adm.schema_ + "Adm.GSP WHERE Description = 'Own Airline'";
        ccs = new SqlConnection(Adm.COnnectionString);
        //convey transaction to db
        cmd = ccs.CreateCommand();
        ccs.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = get_;
        var res =cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        ccs.Close();
        List<GSP> gsp = new List<GSP>();
        GSP temp = new GSP();
        temp.PropertyName = res;
        gsp.Add(temp);
        return gsp;
    }
```

Comment: PropertyName is not being recognised !

Comment: i have given dummy property. change it with your property in class.